# Does python have double import such as C/C++?

Tags: python, module, qt4, importerror

I have a class that I named `Ui_Materials` defined in `materialsFrame.py` When I run the following import in the given file:

```
from common.interface.interface import ShowHide
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 110, in <module>
    main()
  File "./main.py", line 91, in main
    interfaceObj.showMaterials()
  File "/home/mohsen/codes/amlak/amlak/src/common/interface/interface.py", line 80, in showMaterials
    self.ui = Ui_Materials()
NameError: global name 'Ui_Materials' is not defined
```

**Notes:**

1. I have a function in `interfaces` that uses `Ui_materials`
2. When I comment `import line`, everything is OK.

**Question:** How can I solve my problem? I need to import line.

Comment: It's a `class name`, It's no difference When i use `*` instead of `ShowHide`, i get the above result.

Comment: Ok, make sure common.interface.interface is really a python module. Furthermore ShowHide class is inside that module. Can you post the common.interface.interface content? :)

Comment: `common.interface.interface` is a package and i use in another place.

Comment: my `common.interface.interface` : http://paste.debian.net/34035/

Comment: The posted code goes into the `materialsFrame.py`?

Comment: I think i prevent a loop. loop of my modules.

Comment: my `materialsFram.py` : http://paste.debian.net/34036/

Comment: once i remove every `*pyc` but didn't solve.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36690/discussion-between-sgmart-and-mohsen-pahlevanzadeh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import module that contains `Ui_Materials` class into `ShowHide` module.
Be aware that in python you can't perform circular import!! (if first module imports second one, second module must not import first one; also, if first imports second, and third imports first, that means that first and second must not import third one)